# Mysql - output of sum as one of the rows in one field in a single table

Tags: php, mysql, pivot, alias

My statement goes like this:

```
SELECT, id, Subject, score, fm
FROM(
SELECT id, Subject, SUM( score )/SUM(mm)*100 AS score,   
SUM(mm) as fm,
SUM(CASE WHEN enna IN ('test')
            THEN (score)
        END)/SUM(CASE WHEN enna IN ('test')
            THEN (mm)
        END)*100 AS scoreb
FROM table WHERE id ='2' AND Year='2014' 
AND enna = 'exam'  
GROUP BY Subject)r;
```

**[SQL FIDDLE HERE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c1611d/2)**

How can I use test as one of the subject and in the corresponding row  how can I put scoreb as one of the rows in field `score1`. I have been googling and could not find any clue. 
I don't have enough reputation to upload here, so I have uploaded my expected output at

[image]

Comment: Instead of making a picture, just create a fiddle. That will be easy.

Comment: If you create a SqlFiddle, i can take a look.

Comment: Just explain how to calculate the `score` and `mm` for the last row.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this.

### **SQL QUERY**

```
SELECT id,Subject,MAX(Score) AS 'Score',MAX(mm) AS 'fm'
FROM tbl1
GROUP BY Subject
UNION ALL
(SELECT distinct id, 'test' AS Subject,
(SELECT SUM(score) AS 'score' FROM
(SELECT DISTINCT Score FROM tbl1 WHERE enna='test')t1) ,
(SELECT SUM(mm) AS 'fm' FROM
(SELECT DISTINCT mm FROM tbl1 WHERE enna='test')t2)
FROM tbl1
WHERE enna = 'test') ;
```

### **[SQL FIDDLE HERE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c1611d/65)**

Answer (score 1):

I think the easiest way is to use `union all`:

```
SELECT id, Subject, score, mm as fm
FROM table
WHERE id = '2' AND Year='2014' AND enna = 'exam'  
UNION ALL
SELECT id, 'test' as Subject, SUM(score) as score,
       SUM(score)/SUM(mm)*100 AS fm
FROM table
WHERE id = '2' AND Year='2014' AND enna = 'test' ;
```

By the way, I don't get the calculation for `fm`.  The calculation in the queries is different from the results you show.  But that can easily be adjusted.

Comment: Can you please show your Code. Please check my solution http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c1611d/18

Comment: @RoiseAli . . . As a courtesy, you should edit your question or my answer with the code that you actually used.  I know there are differences, your code filters on `id = 2`, but the data only has `id = 1`, for instance.

Comment: @GordonLinoff, the only difference is that I changed `SUM(score) as score` as `SUM(score)/SUM(mm)*100 as score` and I added `SUM(mm)/SUM(mm)*100 as fm and `GROUP BY Subject` in the first `Where` clause. It is working perfect. Thanks once again.